Is there any way to invert numlock indicator LED on Windows?
I use my numpad primarily for typing numbers, and since that means number lock is on, there is a bright undimmable LED on my keyboard which indicates this.
Is there a way to invert the LED so that it is on when numlock is off and vice versa?
As far as I understand, it’s possible to achieve in software way. Maybe there is some way to configure it using some PowerShell command or script, or any other way to get it to work.
So, can anybody help with inverting numlock indicator light on Windows?

Not without hardware hacking.

@DavidPostill. Actually, no. See this relevant SuperUser Post. At least the keyboard driver has the power to do what OP wants, and I suspect (but cannot confirm) that either AutoHotKey or QMK can also help OP out.
